# A generalization of the Casas-Alvero conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

The [Casas-Alvero conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casas-Alvero_conjecture) claims that over a characteristic 0 field, any degree $d$ polynomial $f(x)$ such that, for all $0 \leq i \leq d-1$, $$\gcd(f,f^{(i)}) \neq 1$$ must have exactly one root in the algebraic closure.

I'm proposing a generalization of this conjecture: Suppose there exists $n \leq d$ such that for all $1 \leq j < n$, $$\gcd(f, f^{(d-j)}) \neq 1.$$ Then $f$ does not have exactly $n$ roots in the algebraic closure. This would imply Casas-Alvero by a simple induction argument.

I have proven this conjecture in $\mathbb{C}$ for $n=2$ and $3$, but $n=4$ seems quite a bit harder. Perhaps there is a simple counterexample, but my programming skills are not up to the task to search for it. (I'd be happy to provide my proof in these two cases to those who are interested - it uses the [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) and is in my opinion quite pleasing.)

Comment: Note that this generalisation does not hold for all fields of characteristic 0: if it's not algebraically closed then we can construct simple conditions which imply the existence of counterexamples. E.g. for $n=2$ we can take $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x^2-x+1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$: it has exactly two roots, but $f^{(3)}(x) = 24(x-1)$. Here the condition was the existence of $p>0$, $q>0$, $r > 1$, $a \neq b$ such that there is an irreducible polynomial $g(x) = x^r + (qb - (q+r)a)x^{r-1} + O(x^{r-2})$ yielding $f(x) = (x-a)^p (x-b)^q g(x)$.

Comment: Good point! I have altered the conjecture to say "n roots in the algebraic closure".